# find and replace characters in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace word after finding a specific word in a file using python. I tried re.replace or re.sub function but does not get help.

File Contents :

hostname: "abc-myvm-lx01"

I want to keep "hostname: " as static and replace rest of values.

After replacement file will be look like :

hostname: "abc-urvm-lx02"

Comment: Please show the code you've tried

Comment: If you have a dict you should use replace on values only.

Answer (score 0):

How about parsing the file yourself:

```
# READ ENTRIES FROM FILE
entries = {}
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as file:
   for line in file:
      entry = line.split(':')
      # Allow values like abc:myvm:lx01
      entries[entry[0]] = ':'.join(entry[1:]).strip()

# Modify entries['hostname'] in any way you want

# WRITE ENTRIES TO FILE
with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines('{}: {}\n'.format(*entry) for entry in entries.items())
```